# Compiling with gfortran and ifort

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile a large group of codes for solving a physics problem. I usually use `gfortran`. There is no compile time error. My `gfortran` compiler statement is

```
gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -O -Waliasing -Wampersand -Wconversion -Wsurprising -Wintrinsics-std -Wintrinsic-shadow -Wline-truncation -Wreal-q-constant
```

When executed, I get a runtime error

```
Program received signal SIGBUS: Access to an undefined portion of a memory object.
```

But this runtime error does not occur, when I compile with the debugging flag `-g` or with Intel compiler `ifort`.

Even with `gfortran` without the `-g` flag, sometime this error does not occur! I know that this can be caused by some undefined array or unallocated array or something like this. My problem is that I can not seem to find out where is problem as apparently, I have no compile-time error.

So, is there a compiler flag for `gfortran` or for `ifort` which can help me detect this error?

Thanks

Madhurjya

Comment: gfortran provides options for debugging your issue.  Try -fcheck=all.  Also, use -Wall  option to find suspicious code and fix all warnings.  Finally, don't use -fdefault-real-8 as it may or may not do what you think it does.

Comment: Try adding `-check` to ifort.

Comment: Well -check covers -check bounds and also uninitialised variables... it is usually one or the other 99% of the time. There is also the -gen-interfaces:nosource or something like that in ifort... so I would suggest that as well... interfaces were one of the more common ways to fail in the olden days.